# Find closed form of sequence with high school level math

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following sequence:
$$a_{n+1}=ka_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$$ where $k<1$ and $a_0=100$.

Is there a closed form for $a_n$? I've seen a similar sequence that converges to $\sqrt{2}$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936957/prove-that-a-sequence-converges-to-sqrt2) but is it possible without using hyperbolic geometry as much as possible?

Comment: 1) The case $k=\frac12$ is very special : it is known as the "babylonian method" for extracting square roots. 2) You must mean 'hyperbolic **trigonometry**" not **geometry**. 3) Is $k$ > 0 ?

Comment: For such sequences like the sequence $x_n=\sqrt{2}\coth\left(2^{n-1}\mathrm{arccoth} (x_1)\right)$, you can notice that it can be written under the form $x_n=a f\left(2^{n-1}f^{-1}(x_1)\right)$ (like in linear algebra you have "conjugation" transformation $M'=FMF^{-1}$). This will exactly be the same for your sequence (with a general value of $k$) for a certain function $f$ and a constant $a$. Is there a simple enough function $f$ for your case ?

Comment: @chankelvin Do you really need the closed form, or you just want to compute the limit? Your sequence converges to $\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-k}}$.